# Sum of numbers and cubing numbers in C#

Tags: c#, sum

Hey I am slightly new to C# it has been a week today. Ive managed to get this far but I cant seem to just out put the sum of the even numbers I've cubed i get the whole output and the last number is the total summed except i just want the last to show. Any help would be much appreciated and apologies for the horrendous code. Thanks

```
using System;

public class Test
{
   public static void Main()
   {

       int j = 0; //Declaring + Assigning the interger j with 0
       int Evennums = 0; // Declaring + Assigning the interger Evennums with 0
       int Oddnums = 0; //Declaring + Assigning the interger Oddnums with 0
       System.Console.WriteLine("Calculate the sum of all even numbers between 0 and the           user’s number then cube it!"); //Telling console to write what is in ""
       Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
       uint i = uint.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
       Console.WriteLine("You entered: " + i);
       Console.WriteLine("Your number cubed: " + i*i*i);

      if (i % 2 == 0)
         while (j <= i * i * i) 
          {
            if(j % 2 == 0)
            {
                Evennums += j; //or sum = sum + j;
                Console.WriteLine("Even numbers summed together " + Evennums);
            }
            //increment j
            j++;


          }
    else if(i%2 != 0)
        //reset j to 0 like this: j=0;
        j=0;
        while (j<= i * i * i)
        {
            if (j%2 == 0)
            {
                Oddnums += j;
                //Console.WriteLine(Oddnums);
            }
            //increment j
            j++;

     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the console output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to show the last sum, but not every summing process, change the location of print statement

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
 {
     while (j <= i * i * i) 
      {
        if(j % 2 == 0)
        {
            Evennums += j; //or sum = sum + j;

        }
        //increment j
        j++;


      }
      Console.WriteLine("Even numbers summed together " + Evennums);
}
```

same thing applies for the else if block.

Comment: Thanks it works didn't realise it was that simple! I just get a duplicate sum when ever i do even numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to achieve that you want like below, using LINQ:

```
// Calculate the cube of i.
int cube = i*i*i;

int sum = 0;
string message;

// Check if cube is even.
if(cube%2==0)
{
    sum = Enumerable.Range(0,cube).Where(x => x%2==0).Sum();
    message = "The sum of the even numbers in range [0,"+cube+"] is: ";
}
else // The cube is odd.
{
    sum = Enumerable.Range(0,cube).Where(x => x%2==1).Sum();
    message = "The sum of the odd numbers in range [0,"+cube+"] is: ";
}

// Print the sum.
Console.WriteLine(message+sum);
```